# How to get the nth character in extremely large text file?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a very large text file (~40GB) containing unseparated digits. It's been a while since I've dealt with file I/O in python (or python more generally), and I remember some wizardry with generators being used to access such files. Google yielded little specific help; it seems like everyone deals with sensibly-formatted data they can access line-by-line. All I need to do is read the nth character without destroying the kernel by reading too much into RAM. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the n'th *character* or the n'th *byte*?

Comment: I think you should include the encoding of your file in the question, because the size of a characted varies in function of its encoding

Comment: As pointed out already, the encoding is important.  We can never handle text competently without knowing the encoding.  If you are using a variable-width encoding (e.g. utf8), then you will essentially need to step through every byte from the beginning of the file to guarantee the correct character count.  If you need to do this frequently, you should consider creating some kind of index of the file for faster lookups

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`f.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to get the nth byte in the file. In most common encodings, it's also the nth character:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    char = f.seek(N - 1)
```

Comment: ``seek`` will to to the nth byte, not the nth character.

Comment: @MikeScotty Yes, but OP's file of numbers is most likely encoded as 1 byte = 1 char.

Comment: @ruohola "most likely" is guessing. It would be better to clarify in comments on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use *seek* which will move reading file to given position. Then call *read*.

Additionally, if you don't want indeed any extra data being loaded to memory during read (just one byte/char) use also `buffering=0` when opening a file.

```
with open("largeFile", buffering=0) as f:
    f.seek(10000)
    char = f.read(1)
```